# React Native: Change boolean value of component property depending on if active or not

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native component that consists of 3 buttons components, each one has a boolean property called `inner`. If `inner={true}` then the button appears pressed in, whereas if `inner={false}` then the button appears embossed.

Only one button can be active at any one time, I'd like to make it such that the active button will display `inner={true}` and the other two inactive buttons will display `inner={false}`.

Here is my code below:

```
const ChoiceContainer = props => {
  const {children} = props;

  return <View>{children}</View>;
};

const SendTransaction = () => (
  <ChoiceContainer>
    <Text>Component 1</Text>
  </ChoiceContainer>
);

const Remove = () => (
  <ChoiceContainer>
    <Text>Component 2</Text>
  </ChoiceContainer>
);

const History = () => (
  <ChoiceContainer>
    <Text>Component 3</Text>
  </ChoiceContainer>
);

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    sceneType: 'add',
  };

  showSend = () => {
    this.setState({sceneType: 'add'});
  };

  showReceive = () => {
    this.setState({sceneType: 'remove'});
  };

  showHistory = () => {
    this.setState({sceneType: 'history'});
  };

  renderScene = type => {
    if (type === 'add') {
      return <SendTransaction />;
    }

    if (type === 'remove') {
      return <ReceiveTransaction />;
    }

    if (type === 'history') {
      return <TransactionHistory />;
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {sceneType} = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showAdd}>
            <Button inner={true}>Button 1</Button>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showRemove}>
            <Button inner={false}>Button 2</Button>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showHistory}>
            <Button inner={false}>Button 3</Button>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View>{this.renderScene(sceneType)}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showAdd}>
        <Button inner={sceneType === 'add' }>Button 1</Button>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showRemove}>
        <Button inner={sceneType === 'remove'}>Button 2</Button>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showHistory}>
        <Button inner={sceneType=== 'history'}>Button 3</Button>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: That worked - I did not realize I could pass conditions in like that. Thank you so much!